# Adding dynamical columns based on previous row values with PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my case I have a dataframe that shows "Days" horizontally and in the columns the sold units of each hour. However, I would also like to display 26 hours. The first two hours of the previous day should be used as values and added as columns "24" and "25".

This is what the frame currently looks like:

`| Day | 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15| 16| 17| 18| 19| 20| 21| 22| 23| Yesterday| 
|2012-01-04| 3|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 1|null| 3|null|null| 2| 4| 2| 4| 2| 2| 2| 4| 1| 1| 2|2012-01-03| 
|2012-01-05|null|null|null|null|null| 1| 1| 36| 136| 65| 1| 8| 2| 4|null| 3| 2| 11| 2| 6| 5| 2|null|null|2012-01-04| 
|2012-01-06|null| 1|null|null|null| 1| 6| 32| 118| 88| 6| 1| 2| 2| 2| 6| 4| 3| 5| 4| 1| 3| 1|null|2012-01-05| 
|2012-01-07| 1|null|null|null|null|null| 4| 39| 128| 65| 3| 3| 7| 1| 4| 1| 4| 3| 4| 6| 1| 3| 1| 2|2012-01-06|`

I already tried to link the data with the previous day via `left-join`, but Spark gives me the error message every time:

`AnalysisException: u'Detected implicit cartesian product for LEFT OUTER join between logical plans`

The join to tie the data with the previous day:

```py
df = df.alias("a").join(df, df["Yesterday"] == df["Day"], how="left").select("a.*", df["Day"].alias("Day1"))
```

A normal join doesn't seem to solve that. How can I easily add columns that take the row values of the previous day? So something like `shift`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Data frame containing data from your example:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, LongType, StringType
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
>>> data = [('2012-01-04',3,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,1,None,3,None,None,2,4,2,4,2,2,2,4,1,1,2,'2012-01-03'),
...         ('2012-01-05',None,None,None,None,None,1,1,36,136,65,1,8,2,4,None,3,2,11,2,6,5,2,None,None,'2012-01-04'),
...         ('2012-01-06',None,1,None,None,None,1,6,32,118,88,6,1,2,2,2,6,4,3,5,4,1,3,1,None,'2012-01-05'),
...         ('2012-01-07',1,None,None,None,None,None,4,39,128,65,3,3,7,1,4,1,4,3,4,6,1,3,1,2,'2012-01-06')]
>>> columns = ['Day','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','Yesterday']
>>> schema = StructType([StructField(c, LongType() if c.isdigit() else StringType(), True) for c in columns])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
>>> df.show(5, False)
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+----+---+----+----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+
|Day       |0   |1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |7   |8  |9   |10 |11  |12  |13 |14  |15 |16 |17 |18 |19 |20 |21 |22  |23  |Yesterday |
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+----+---+----+----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+
|2012-01-04|3   |null|null|null|null|null|null|null|1  |null|3  |null|null|2  |4   |2  |4  |2  |2  |2  |4  |1  |1   |2   |2012-01-03|
|2012-01-05|null|null|null|null|null|1   |1   |36  |136|65  |1  |8   |2   |4  |null|3  |2  |11 |2  |6  |5  |2  |null|null|2012-01-04|
|2012-01-06|null|1   |null|null|null|1   |6   |32  |118|88  |6  |1   |2   |2  |2   |6  |4  |3  |5  |4  |1  |3  |1   |null|2012-01-05|
|2012-01-07|1   |null|null|null|null|null|4   |39  |128|65  |3  |3   |7   |1  |4   |1  |4  |3  |4  |6  |1  |3  |1   |2   |2012-01-06|
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+----+---+----+----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+
```

LEFT joining the Data frame with itself, and adding two first hours of yesterday as hours '24' and '25':

```
>>> newdf = df.alias('l').join(df.alias('r'), col('l.Yesterday') == col('r.Day'), how='left').select(col('l.*'), col('r.0').alias('24'), col('r.1').alias('25'))
>>> newdf.show(5, False)
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+----+---+----+----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+----+----+
|Day       |0   |1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |7   |8  |9   |10 |11  |12  |13 |14  |15 |16 |17 |18 |19 |20 |21 |22  |23  |Yesterday |24  |25  |
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+----+---+----+----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+----+----+
|2012-01-07|1   |null|null|null|null|null|4   |39  |128|65  |3  |3   |7   |1  |4   |1  |4  |3  |4  |6  |1  |3  |1   |2   |2012-01-06|null|1   |
|2012-01-04|3   |null|null|null|null|null|null|null|1  |null|3  |null|null|2  |4   |2  |4  |2  |2  |2  |4  |1  |1   |2   |2012-01-03|null|null|
|2012-01-06|null|1   |null|null|null|1   |6   |32  |118|88  |6  |1   |2   |2  |2   |6  |4  |3  |5  |4  |1  |3  |1   |null|2012-01-05|null|null|
|2012-01-05|null|null|null|null|null|1   |1   |36  |136|65  |1  |8   |2   |4  |null|3  |2  |11 |2  |6  |5  |2  |null|null|2012-01-04|3   |null|
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+----+---+----+----+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------+----+----+
```

Comment: Okay, works well. But I tried to make it more dynamically like this:                             ```python i in range(x):
                        df = df.alias('l').join(df.alias('r'), col('l.Yesterday'+`j`) == col('r.Day'), how='left').select(col('l.*'), col('r.'+`z`).alias(''+`i`))
                        i += 1
                        z += 1 ```                                                                                                       But this is quite inefficient... Is there a faster way or possibility to add them dynamically? Mabye adding a list for the select?

Comment: `select()` accepts list of columns, and you can construct that list dynamically: `select([col('l.*')] + [col('r.'+z).alias(' '+i) for i,z in ...])`